# Swiftmailer mail limit

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm working on an app that allows you to buy ebooks and have them sent to your kindle. However there is a max mail limit on smtp server at 10mb. Does anyone know how to increase this limit?

Cheers,

Keith.

Obligatory code so that I can actually post the question:

Config.php:

```
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
port:      "%mailer_port%"
spool:     { type: memory }
encryption: null
```

Comment: ahm .. where did you find, that Swiftmailer has a limit of *10MB*?

Comment: Well when I use it to send a message under 10MB seems to work no problem but >10MB the message doesn't send plus in the web debug toolbar that comes bundled with Symfony I get this error under the email section: ERROR - Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 message too large "

Comment: and as you know ... SMTP Server != Swift

Comment: Ok I didn't know but I do now. Cheers. But regardless is it possible to remove the limit on SMTP servers?

Comment: Yes No ... Is it your server? Is it the client server (Mail Server of the receiver mail) ... If all is yours, then the answer would be YES

Comment: I think that would be limited on the SMTP server itself, within the configuration. If it's not your server specifically (e.g. shared server), the server admin may be able to increase this limit.